# Hi I am trying to get the computer to join my classes in Teams, but Only pyautogui works or webbrowser

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui, python-webbrowser

I cant manage to get this working, I have tried all day. Whenever I run pyautogui and webbrower separately they both do what I want them to, but whenever I run the whole thing, just one of them, I appreciate any help, thanks,  here is the code:

```
import webbrowser
import datetime
import pyautogui as pg
import time


from datetime import datetime

chrome = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
classtime = "22:07"

while True:
    lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    if lcltime == classtime:
        webbrowser.get(chrome).open_new("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_MWQ4NWUxMTQtN2FjMS00NjVhLThhZjMtZDc3M2Q1ZjQ3MmE5%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2235d5a561-a7d7-4520-a5ea-e0e191bd5c09%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22b4f18596-fcbe-4fef-8c34-488f147e11c2%22%7d")
        break

time.sleep(1)
clck = pg.moveTo(1115,473,3)
clck = pg.click(1115,473)

clck = pg.moveTo(1493,755,2)
clck = pg.click(1493,755)
```

Comment: Why don't you use only pyautogui or only webbrowser, if each of them does what you want alone?

Answer (score 0):

`webbrowser` always uses the screen size of your computer, as such if the code can work on your computer, it may fail to work on another computer with a different screen size because the 
`clck = pg.moveTo(1115,473,3)`
`clck = pg.click(1115,473)`
are specific in the positions.

For the code to be universal, I would suggest you use `pywebview` which you can specify the screen size of the window you want to open, and your parameters of the `pg.moveTo(1115,473,3)` will be precise and universal on all screens